# Coq: evaluating/simplifying `Prop` tautologies

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I'm proving some basic facts about ultrafilters in Coq, and many of my proofs eventually get to the stage where I have to prove a goal such as

```
(False -> False) = True
```

or

```
False /\ P = False
```

or

```
True
```

or some other trivial tautology. Neither `simpl` nor `auto` seem to do anything, so how can I solve these `Prop` goals?

Comment: If you get a goal like this, you usually have done something "wrong" in how you formulated the problem.  Just as @Meven suggests, try to reformulate the problem so that you use `<->` to compare propositional truths instead of `=`.

Comment: For future reference, if you replace the equalities `=` with logical equivalences `<->`, then you can prove the propositional tautologies with the `tauto` tactic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how you encoded your ultrafilters, but your first two goals are not provable. Indeed, they assert equalities between different *types*, which there is no way to prove in vanilla Coq. There are multiple different ways to go around the problem, however.

The easiest (and in my opinion best) solution is to replace equality of propositions with logical equivalence in all your definitions. In your first case for instance, you would obtain `(False -> False) <-> True` which is indeed a tautology.

Alternatively, you can replace propositions by booleans altogether, i.e. use `bool` instead of `Prop` in the definition ultrafilter, and rely on boolean connectives instead of propositional ones. Your second case would become something like `false && P = false`, which is again provable, because your are dealing with equality between elements of an inductive type rather than between propositions. But this change is quite heavier than the previous one as it would imply much more changes to your development to reason with booleans rather than propositions. If you go this path, you might want to look at MathComp, which plays a lot with booleans in this kind of settings.

The last possibility is a bit more tricky, it relies on the so-called *propositional extensionality* axiom, which states that two propositions are equal whenever they are equivalent. In Coq, it corresponds to

```
prop_ext : forall P Q : Prop, (P <-> Q) -> P = Q.
```

Using this axiom you can reduce your various equality goals to equivalences, which are true as mentioned in the first solution. A similar axiom appears in the context of Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT), as a consequence of the univalence axiom that is central there, although the notion of proposition in Coq and in HoTT are somewhat different. If you are curious about the difference between equality and equivalence you might want to check it up, which is why I mention it, but I would recommand going for the first solution instead, as it avoids having to rely on an unneeded axiom.

Comment: I understand what you meant, but strictly speaking, propositional extensionality in Coq is not a consequence of univalence, because propositions in HoTT and Coq are different things: the first is a structure on `Type`, whereas the second is a special sort. Propositional extensionality is more basic than full univalence, and I think it is fine to use the former without understanding the latter.

Comment: Right, I wanted to give a pointer in the direction where you can find more infos about propositional extensionality and overlooked that difference. I’ll edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: I encoded sets as functions `nat -> Prop` and (ultra)filters as functions `set -> Prop`. I was originally using `bool` instead of `Prop`, but then I don't see how I can define the Frechet filter: `Example Frechet : family := fun A => exists n:nat, forall m:nat, m>n -> m in A.`

Comment: Indeed, you would not be able to do that, because a function `(nat -> bool) -> bool` denotes a decidable ultrafilter, and the Frechet filter is not decidable since you cannot in general decide whether a given function is ultimately always true.